# nodemailer verify is returning success even with bad credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

so I am trying to create a gmail client as a learning project. I am using nodemailer module to verify credentials and send mails. My code is as follows

```js
let data ;
    req.setEncoding('utf8') ;
    await req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data = query.parse(chunk) ;
    });

    const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({service: 'gmail'}) ;

    mailer.options.auth = await data ;

    mailer.verify((err, suc) => {
        if (mailer.options.auth === undefined) {
          console.log("No Credentials") ;
        }
        else if (err) {
            console.log("Error : ") ;
        } else {
            console.log("success") ;
        }
      }) ;
```

> PS : the function wrapping it is a async arrow function

It is correctly logging `"No Credentials"` when the post data received from form is empty, It is logging `"success"` even if entered credentials are wrong. I hope for a solution soon, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should log the seccond, `suc` parameter ? And not only test/verify for "useless" stuff. You test just if there are credentials and or an error but not for the "suc"

Comment: when I tested (verified) with wrong password earlier it actually produced an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it myself and I've came to these 2 conclusions :

- I haven't found any way to re-set the `auth` property after having created the `Mail` object using `createTransport()` method. Maybe there is one, maybe not. You're gonna have to look into it.
- The `verify()` method does not check if the `auth` object is defined but rather checks if the props that it contains are defined and valid

But here's what I did and that works :

```
// the function returns an object of type { user: string, pass: string }
const credentials = await getMyAuthData();
const config = {
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: credentials
};

const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(config);

mailer.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(success);
});
```